# Execute shell command using qmake

Tags: c++, qt, shell, cmake, qmake

I want to execute a shell command using **qmake**. The command is :

> idlpp -S -l cpp MyModel.idl

This processes my IDL and generates some .cpp and .h files that I am including in my project. Right now I am executing it manually from a terminal but I want it to be automatically done when I run qmake.

What should I add in my **.pro** file? Is there something equivalent to the **execute_process()** used by **cmake**?

Comment: You probably don't want to run it from qmake, but from the makefile itself, so that whenever you change MyModel.idl, the output will be regenerated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [system()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command) function in .pro file

Answer (score 6):

You should use [QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-extra-compilers) (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers)

It will not call  `idlpp` when running `qmake`, but when running `make`. However doing so will integrate the `idlpp` call as part of the make process.

```
# Sample IDL .pro compiler
IDL_FILES = MyModel.idl
idl_compiler.output = idl_${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.cpp
idl_compiler.commands = idlpp -S -l cpp ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} # Ideally you would add something like --output=${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
idl_compiler.input = IDL_FILES
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += idl_compiler
```